Move Audit trail data from Marketing cloud SFTP server to External SFTP location
I'm now on the process of moving Audit trail data to external sFTP location,and the original process includes moving data directly from safehouse to external sFTP.
But I wonder if it is possible to move data from Marketing cloud SFTP to external location, adding the another step of moving data from safehouse to marketing cloud sFTP location.
Has anyone try this? or if anyone can gives me insight on this, it would be greatly helpful.

Can you help me understand why you are trying to do this? Seems like an unnecessary extra step?

I initially tried moving directly from safehouse to external location, but the automation  keeps saying that 'The socket on the remote server was closed unexpectedly.' I think the marketing cloud server ip address is not properly whitelisted from the external location. So I've been thinking about alternatives, moving file from marketing cloud sftp to external location.

wouldnt moving the file (= write file to server as SFMC) run into the exact same constraint as exporting it (= write file to server as SFMC)? I would say you need to probably address the root cause.
